# Вопрос по работе Javascript

Tags: javascript

Короче, такие дела. Я 1 день в JS. После С++ это выглядит как коньяк с ядом. Сначала всё идёт норм, а потом вдруг ошибка. 
Вот немного исправленный код из скрипта.

```
var X;

function On_Command(Player, cmd, args) {

if (cmd == "SetX") {
Player.Message ("X is set!")
...
X = 1;}

if (cmd == "ResetX") {
Player.Message ("X is reset!")
...
X = 0;}

if (cmd == "GetX") {

if (X == 1) {
...}

if (X == 0) {
...}

else {
...
Player.Message ("Error! X is " + X + " !");}
}
}
```

Вот сама часть которая не работает. Не могу найти ошибку. Приведу процесс на примере того что здесь написано(у меня код на другую тему написан и объяснить всё будет сложнее).

Запускаю, пишу SetX, мне выходит моё сообщение что всё успешно прошло. Далее ввожу GetX мне пишет что переменная X не определена. Я пробовал делать return(X), в итоге получаю двойное сообщение об успешном назначении переменной X, но GetX опять же не работает. Пишет undefined.
Помогите пожалуйста.

PS. Ещё тут такая ерунда, мне надо 5+ минут чтобы проверить работоспособность кода(Создание сервера на уд.компьютере и подключение к серверу). Если тут такие программы как MVSC++ ? Подскажите пожалуйста, а тот так невозможно.

PSS. Сама Java запускает код и ничего не выявляет в 95% ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И что не так? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aj0sdsy0/

Вот чуть более правильно. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aj0sdsy0/2/

PS: есть jslint и куча разных способов делать unit tests.

PSS: **java!=javascript**

Comment: спасибо за ответы.
"вот чуть более правильно. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aj0sdsy0/2/"
сейчас проверю.
"PSS: java!=javascript"
Я имел в виду MS Windows Based Script Host, моя ошибка.

Comment: Всё заработало. Спасибо. Дело было в if (X == 1). Нужно написать if (X === 1).